# inner join two tables and count some variables

Tags: database, sql-query-store

I have two tables

- ERHAN_FLASH
- ERHAN_FLASH_NAME

ERHAN_FLASH:

```
COMPANY CONTENTNUMBER
TELEKOM 11146
TELEKOM 11146
TELEKOM 11146
TELEKOM 11146
TELEKOM 11146
TELEKOM 11147
TELEKOM 11147
TELEKOM 11147
TELEKOM 11147
TELEKOM 11147
```

ERHAN_FLASH_NAME:

```
EGIA_CONTENT_NAME               EGI_CONTENT_CODE
Keyif Veren Sunum               510
Musteri Odakli icerik Yonetimi  2467
Temel Yonetim Becerileri        2469
Veritabani Dosyalama Sistemleri 2889
Sunum                           2890
```

EGI_CONTENT_CODE equals CONTENTNUMBER

I need to count these table like

```
CONTENTNUMBER EGIA_CONTENT_NAME  COUNT
11146          CONTENT1          146
11147          CONTENT2           42
12456          NULL               12
```

but some variables IN ERHAN_FLASH_NAME EGI_CONTENT_CODE is null

how can I join these 2 tables and count

Answer (score 0):

You use JOIN to join the tables and GROUP BY to count.

```sql
select EF.CONTENTNUMBER
      ,EFN.EGIA_CONTENT_NAME
      ,count(*) as COUNT
  from ERHAN_FLASH EF
  left join ERHAN_FLASH_NAME EFN
    on EF.CONTENTNUMBER = EFN.EGI_CONTENT_CODE
 group by EF.CONTENTNUMBER
         ,EFN.EGIA_CONTENT_NAME
```

Comment: Hello, thank you but this query only show  include content table without  EGIA_CONTENT_NAME  equals NULL

Example:
This is not show 
```
CONTENTNUMBER  EGIA_CONTENT_NAME  COUNT
12456                                   NULL                           12
```
@Abra

Answer (score 0):

thank you but this query only show include content table without EGIA_CONTENT_NAME equals NULL Example: This is not show

```
 CONTENTNUMBER EGIA_CONTENT_NAME COUNT
 12456          NULL               12
```

@Abra

Comment: Have you taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)? Have you visited the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)? Answers are meant to answer the question. Are you answering your own question? Adding a comment to my answer is all you need to do. If this is not an answer then I suggest that you delete it.